# Read data from CSV file, perform stop word removal and write to another CSV file

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to perform stop word removal in a csv file and write the results to another csv. Below is the code I have written :

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import csv
import codecs

f = codecs.open("F:/mtech/Project/answer_sample.csv","r","utf-8")
answers = f.read()
f.close()
file_out = open('answer_swr','w')
unicode(answers)
#for x in answers:
#    print("type of x is")
#    print type(x)
#for y in stopwords.words('english'):
#    print("type of y is")
for line in answers:
    stop_words=set(stopwords.words("english"))
    words=word_tokenize(line)
    filtered_sentence=[""]
    for n in words:
        if n not in stop_words:
            filtered_sentence.append(""+n)
    file_out.writelines(filtered_sentence+["\n"])
print("Stop words removed..")
```

and I am receiving an error:

```
file_out.writelines(filtered_sentence+["\n"])
TypeError: writelines() argument must be a sequence of strings
```

Comment: Please do not post an image of your code but paste it into your question directly. This makes it easier for other to help.

Comment: What does "stop word removal" mean?

Comment: Besides, why don't you simply check what input your are passing to function `writelines`, and why that input is not a sequence of strings (as what it should be, according to the error that you're getting)???

Comment: @PhillipD I have posted my code.

Comment: @goodvibration the input is in unicode format as required for stopwords. but function writeline requires a string. I tried typecasting as well. Its not working.

Comment: @goodvibration Stop words are the words that are not important in analyzing text. for e.g. "and" , "this" etc.

Comment: You're calling `writelines`, not `writeline` , and to the best of my knowledge, this function takes a list of strings, not a single string.

Comment: BTW, you probably want to call `f.readlines()` (which returns a list of strings), not `f.read()` (which returns a single string). When iterating the string returned by `f.read()`, you are iterating the contents of your file character by character.

Comment: BTW #2, what are you hoping to achieve with `unicode(answers)`??? The result of this expression is immediately "trashed". If you want to convert `answers` to unicode then you need to store the result, i.e., `answers = unicode(answers)`.

Comment: Please post a sample inputs / expected outputs

Comment: I tried using f.readlines(), but the output is incorrect. I need the words in all the columns of the csv file separately.

Comment: @AyushiMisra I repeat: PLEASE POST A SAMPLE INPUTS / EXPECTED OUTPUTS

Comment: Also if you want to respect the csv format, by all means use the csv module

Comment: Thankyou for ur help! Its working now!